# Forward/redirect msgs from DNN internal msging system into Vivo messaging

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-imc

I don't know how big the community that uses DNN VivoSocial out there, but I'll give it a shot.

So I am using DNN Vivo Messaging (part of Vivo Social), is there anyway I can redirect/forward all the incoming messages from DNN internal messaging into Vivo Messaging?

Answer (score 0):

Dhana there wouldn't be any built in way to do this. Most of the time when working with 3rd party modules you will need to do some coding or something to get other modules to get data and interact with it.  Some of the new features of DNN5 should help with this, but they currently do not.

One way I can think of that is not super great is to use SQL Server triggers to move data to the other database tables.  For example: Whenever a private message is sent it will be saved into a DNN database table. Put an insert trigger on that, whenever that is added you could then add that message to Vivo.  Or vice versa.  It's...  a way.